# Avada theme overwrite own css

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using Avada template and create child theme. In style.css I don't have any solution to overwrite default .css styles from Avada. Only possible solution is using !important , anyone know how to overwrite Avada .css without using !important

Comment: What did you do by far in order to achieve what you've intended?

Comment: Stack Overflow should not be mistaken for [**Avada support forum**](https://theme-fusion.com/support/). Your post is **off-topic** for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

Please use custom css option. You can write css here it would overwrite the Avada css. Please check out the documentation https://theme-fusion.com/knowledgebase/how-to-make-custom-css-changes/

Answer (score 0):

You can make usage of the Custom CSS feature available in the backend or many of the blocks being used by the Fusion Builder, which comes with Avada, have the availability to configure certain design elements from within them.

If you do want to use a child theme, be aware that Avada uses many !important rules in their stylesheet while other styling is being handled by either the fusion builder or javascript logic.